# Is there anyway to install scala without sbt?

Tags: scala, installation, sbt, fedora, yum

I have a fedora system. I need to install scala. I have searched online and it says to install sbt. I don't want to install sbt. Is there anyway to install just scala. Like is there a command like `sudo yum install scala` that will solve my problem?

Comment: Whats wrong with `sudo yum install scala`? You don't need sbt to install scala. sbt is just another build tool like maven.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have Java installed:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

Then download and install Scala:

```
wget http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.11.7.tgz
tar xvf scala-2.11.7.tgz
sudo mv scala-2.11.7 /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/scala-2.11.7 /usr/lib/scala
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/scala/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
rm scala-2.11.7.tgz
```